# Find the equation of the tangent plane given a vector instead of point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

1. Find the equation of the tangent plane at $\mathbf p = (0,0)$ on the surface $z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$.
2. Give an intuitive geometric argument to support the result.

However $\mathbf p$ is a vector.

I see that the surface of $z$ represents a sphere. 
Thanks.

Additional:
I found the tangent plane equation to be $0=1-z$, but I am having trouble answering the second question.

Comment: I'm sure that you just need to find the value of z given (x,y) = (0,0).

Comment: By the way, it's half a sphere, not a full one.

Comment: Could anyone point me in the right direction for question 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal vector at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by:
$$
\mathbf{n} = (-f_x,-f_y,1)|_{(x,y)= (x_0,y_0)} = \left(\frac{2x_0}{\sqrt{1-x_0^2 -y_0^2}}, \frac{2y_0}{\sqrt{1-x_0^2 -y_0^2}},1\right) = (0,0,1).
$$
The tangent plane is 
$$
\mathbf{n}\cdot(x-x_0,y-y_0,z - f(x_0,y_0)) = (0,0,1)\cdot (0,0,z-1)= 0,
$$
geometrically speaking, this means:

> The tangent plane at $(x,y)= (0,0)$ is perpendicular to the normal vector of the surface $z = f(x,y)|_{(x,y)= (0,0)}$.

Hence the plane is $z -1=0$.

Moreover, the normal vector is $(0,0,1)$, which points along the positive direction of $z$-axis, the plane perpendicular to this vector must be a "vertical" shift (shift along the $z$-axis) of the $xy$-plane $z=0$, hence it must be $z = a$. Now for the plane must pass through $(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$, which is $(0,0,1)$ in your case, this implies $a=1$.